# Making a Continuous, Differentiable Function that is $0$ At $x=0$ and when $\frac {33}x$ is An Integer

Tags: number-theory, functions

Is there a function $f(x)$, that is continuous, differentiable, is $0$ iff $x=0$ or $\frac {33}x$ is an integer? It should be a single formula (not defined piecewise) and it should not need the factors of $33$ to construct it.

Comment: Is there any context or motivation to this question?

Comment: @Math1000 Well, working on it for another function.

Comment: You can order a non-piecewise definition, but then you have to tell us why one must exist. Otherwise, I'm done with you.

Comment: A piecewise definition *is* a single formula.

Comment: "Not including the factors of $33$" is enough vaguely defined concept for me to tell you to try with $x^9 - 1220 x^7 + 143878 x^5 - 1328580 x^3 + 1185921 x$

Comment: @prosinac Well, it required the factors of $33$ to construct so, it doesn't count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid using a piecewise definition because of $x=0$, which is a limit point of the points $33/n$, $n\in\Bbb Z-\{0\}$.

Try something like
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(33\pi/x), & x\ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0\,.\end{cases}$$

Comment: $f(x)=\lim_{(y\to x^+)}y^2\sin (33\pi/y)$ is the same function. Does this qualify as a non-piecewise def'n?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Very clever :) You don't need the one-sided limit, though.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there exists a continuously differentiable function $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with the property that $f(0)=0$ and $f(n)=33/n$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$.

In fact, you can define $f(x)$ piecewise. It is equal to $33/x$ for all $|x|\geq 1$ and you can find a quartic polynomial that vanishes at $x=0$ and equals $33$ at $x=\pm 1$ and whose derivatives at $x=\pm 1$ match up with $33/x$. The fact that the values and derivatives match, and that the two piecewise parts are each continuously differentiable on their own domains, guarantees that the end result is also continuously differentiable.

Comment: Well, for the function I'm using it for, I need it so that it is a single function (not defined piecewise)

Comment: A piecewise function is still a single function... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Definition. Perhaps you mean for there to be a "single formula"? If so, you will have to formalize what are the exact types of building blocks allowed in your formula. Do you want it to be a polynomial? (If so, easy to see that it is impossible.) Are exponentials allowed? Infinite sums (if so, easy to see that it is possible). Anyway I answered your original question, it is poor form to add additional conditions after a question has been answered.

Comment: I don't think you read the question carefully. OP wants $f(x)=0$ when $x=33/n$ for any nonzero integer $n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think the OP needs to do a better job specifying exactly what they want. As it stands, I find the wording too ambiguous to distinguish between my interpretation and your interpretation.

Comment: @TedShifrin and when $x=0$.

Comment: @pre-kidney: The OP specified it perfectly clearly. The only criticism is that "and" should be "or."

Comment: Anyway, they are both interpretations since the OP's question does not make literal sense.

Comment: @pre-kidney No, yours is pretty objectively not correct. OP's question is unclear, but not in that part

Comment: @TedShifrin i fixed it in that respect.

Comment: @DonThousand How else is my question not clear?